# Как скомпилировать Anti-Grain Geometry для IOS

Tags: objective-c, llvm, ios, gcc, c++

Как скомпилировать Anti-Grain Geometry для IOS? (что бы потом можно было далее использовать в xcode при разработке приложения)

http://www.antigrain.com/doc/introduction/introduction.agdoc.html#toc0010